# converting image extension

Tags: batch-file, image-conversion

Hi need help creating a script to convert the extension of a tif image to a .png and removing the original from the file.

This is what I have. 
@echo off
image1.tif >> image1.png

when it run it show it as a .png but with a blank image. Still haven't figure out how to remove the original one from the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm, assuming that there should be a newline after `@echo off`: What you're doing is appending the output stream from the process running the file image1.tif, to a file image1.png (creating it if it doesn't exist). As the program that opens up image1.tif doesn't write anything to the standard output stream, the other file gets created but is empty. It seems that what you want to be doing (whatever the reason is) is renaming image1.tif to image1.png:

```
ren image1.tif image1.png
```

or copy it:

```
copy image1.tif image1.png
```